# Flutter-Keyboard Is not pushing the View Upword

Tags: android, flutter, forms, keyboard, flutter-getx

I am using flutter Version 3.13.8. Previously  When using SingleChildScrollview the content of the page was pushed above the keyboard and scroll was working good.

But then after update the content is hidden when keyboard is opened, e.g I cant see the text in TextFormFields they hide below keyboard
how can i fix this?

```
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset:true,
```

i have tried both true and false its not working for me either.

The Keyboard shoud push all TextFormFields above

Following is the structure i am using

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        const BackgroundImage(),
        Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
            toolbarHeight: 42.0,
            title: Row(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/left_arrow_50.png',
                    color: const Color(0xfffc9e1e),
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.back(closeOverlays: true);
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Page',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xfffc9e1e), fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: ScrollController(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                child: Obx(() => Column(
    form data) ```
````

Comment: Please add some code snippets

Comment: Could you please specify what you are using as parent widget, is it Column ?

Comment: I have added the parent structure plz check

Answer (score 1):

If your using a column, try to set:

```
crossisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```

…or try to put the content in a `sizedBox` with a height of 110.h.

Comment: Same code is working fine on an older version
my current version is 3.13.8.
Further I have added the  parent widget tree

Answer (score 1):

If you are using package "ScreenUtilInit" just add useInheritedMediaQuery: true, in mian.dart

Comment: Yes, Its working now. Thankyou so much